# TypeScript Run Build Task in Visual Studio Code fails

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, git-bash

I am trying to use the "Run Build Task" command in Visual Studio Code on Windows 10 to compile TypeScript with Git Bash, but I get this error:

[image: TypeScript error]

It seems that the backslashes are being interpreted as escape characters, so they disappear.

This issue does not happen when I switch the default shell to Powershell or cmd.exe. Also, the same issue happens no matter if I install TypeScript globally (`npm i -g typescript`) or locally (`npm i typescript`). Finally, I suspect that my `%PATH%` environment variable may need fixing as well.

This is the `tsconfig.json` file I have been using:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true
  }
}
```

My end goal is to simply press `Ctrl+S` on a TypeScript code file and have it immediately transpile to JavaScript (given the TS file is valid, of course.)

Answer (score 1):

There is an open issue in the vscode repository on GitHub about this. See link

[Paths separators in build config being escaped/stripped out prior to build command being run #35593](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/35593)

The issue is that vscode assumes that Windows paths should be used on a Windows system. However git bash uses UNIX path seperators, which causes the issue.

The user [`Atomfighter10101`](https://github.com/Atomfighter10101) on GitHub suggests:

> In build task change the wrong command of "command": `/c/ProgramData/Anaconda3/python ${file}`, to the right command of "command": 
>   `/c/ProgramData/Anaconda3/python \"${file}\"`.

(*Obviously change python to tsc for your usecase)*